# Deleting lines beginning with a CR in a file directly

Tags: shell, ksh, carriage-return

I want to write a ksh script delete all lines of a file beginning by a carriage return. I want to specify that in the same script I want to reuse the modified file so I need to do the modification directly in the file.

For example here is my file in Notepad ++ (with the carriage return shown as CRLF as its a Windows format file):

```
CE1;CPr1;CRLF
CE2;CPr2;CRLF
CRLF
CE3;CPr3;CRLF
CRLF
CRLF
```

and I want to obtain:

```
CE1;CPr1;CRLF
CE2;CPr2;CRLF
CE3;CPr3;CRLF
```

The script I wrote so far is:

```
sed -i '/^\n/d' ListeTable.lst
```

I also tried with `\r` and `\R` but nothing is working.

As I specify there is a following script that reuse the modified file that looks like (but there is more):

```
echo -n "(CE = '$(tail -n 1 ListeTable.lst | cut -d$';' -f1)'and CPr = '$(tail -n 1 ListeTable.lst | cut -d$';' -f2)')"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a regex that works for this problem : `'/^\s*$/d'` (`\s` = match any whitespace character (newlines, spaces, tabs); `*` = the character may repeat any times or be absent; `$` = to the end of the last \s character found)

So the working code is : `sed -i '/^\s*$/d' ListeTable.lst`